# How to say "please notice that..."

Tags: translation

In a powerpoint presentation context, how can I say :

```
"please notice that..."
```

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be "please note that..."? Anyway, translation requests are unfortunately off topic here.

Comment: @Gerhard: Translation requests are only off-topic, if they are (1) about a larger piece of text or (2) they can easily be answered by a general reference such as a dictionary. Point 1 doesn’t apply here (see also [this recent Meta question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1093/2594)); point 2 is debatable, but can be addressed by the asker elaborating why a dictionary did not help.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: when I enter "please note that" into [leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=please%20note%20that&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on), at I got a direct translation. If anything, I think there is a problem with the English expression, which would be even more off-topic to my mind.

Comment: In a presentation, less text is more, so I would go with [NB](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/NB).

Comment: If you need to express: "Please note..." (or "notice") in a *visual* Powerpoint presentation, you're doing something wrong anyways IMHO. Things to note should be made to stand out *visually*, not *textually*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bitte beachten Sie, dass...", or if it is informal "Bitte beachtet, dass..."